# Ответ бота на ответы боту (aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

пишу телеграмм бота, который будет поддерживать общение в чатах. Проблема состоит в следующем: не могу заставить бота (Нико) отвечать на сообщения, которые были ответом на сообщение бота (reply; фото прилагается).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def reply(message: types.Message):
  if 'Нико' in message.text or 'нико' in message.text:
    response = openai.Completion.create(
      model="text-davinci-003",
      prompt=message.text,
      temperature=0.5,
      max_tokens=300,
      top_p=1.0,
      frequency_penalty=0.5,
      presence_penalty=0.0,
    )
    text = response['choices'][0]['text']
    await message.reply(text)
```

Ps: «Нико» должна реагировать подобным образом:

[image: пример желаемого результата]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Хорошо. Я скорректировал свой вопрос